# How find Bitcoin transaction by the time inclusion in the block?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin

There are many services that provide the ability to find a transaction by its id. For example, such as https://blockexplorer.com/tx/8987fa849d822dbb0e593d9d1b750550efe510b02885239b3d7f318cfd219a07

But, how do I get the transactions that were included in the blocks, not by their ID but by on-time? For example, I need get all transactions that were included in the block "Nov 7, 2015 12:24:07 PM"

Which way I get this transactoins?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the block using unix timestamp(you can convert any time you want into this)

using blockr.io api

http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/block/info/first?after=(timestamp)

it will give you the block hash and some other info that you can use to find the trasactions in the block

hope this helps!